# Offer popover information for tags in jobs section

Tags: feature-request, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

### Explanation:

Currently there is no pop over information when hovering over tags in the jobs section.

Sometimes there are interesting technologies that I haven't heard about and some kind of description could be interesting.

Like for example [featherjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featherjs)

[image]

There is *no* popover information and when clicking on the tag, I get redirected to the jobs page with a search for jobs using [featherjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featherjs).

[image]

### Question:

Couldn't we have something similar like on the main site?

[image]

Comment: I like this a lot - although I wouldn't go quite as far as saying "this is trivial". :-)

Comment: Nah, you're right, it shouldn't be super hard to build. I'll ping our PMs and see what they think.

Comment: True. All good!

Comment: It's on our radar. Not exactly as easy as I thought because the set of tags on Jobs isn't exactly the same as on SO, although there's a lot of overlap. Should have an update in the near future.